# Java and NetBeans: Cannot run code from the compiled file

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been working on a project programmed in Java with Netbeans. Everything is working fine when running inside Netbeans. So I wanted to run from the compiled file, but the file did not open. Trying to figure out what happened, I tried to run the compiled code from the console, but this error appeared:

**Error:** `Could not find or load main class [JAR NAME]`

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, and when searching the web I cannot find my exact problem happening (I find a lot of people complaining that this errors occurs when running from inside their IDE, which I know how to solve)

**EDIT**: I managed to make it run on my Windows computer (development computer) with the line `java -jar JARNAME` but when I try to use this line on my computer running linux the error persists.

The manifest file, "Manifest.mf":

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: firedartsfx.Main
```

I've verified that the main class, that has the public static main function is placed on the Main class and under the package "firedartsfx"

**EDIT 2:** I can't really tell what I did, but that error doesn't occur anymore. Instead it now shows the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

**EDIT 3:** Here's my java version (updated)

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

after updating to this version, the error `Error: Could not find or load main class firedartsfx.Main` persists

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a path issue to me.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is that you probably said `java XXX.jar`, and that's not how it works. If the jar is runnable, you need to say `java -jar XXX.jar`. If it not runnable, you need to say `java -cp XXX.jar com.example.MyClass`, or whatever your class name is.

Comment: Does the mainfest of the jar file include a entry for the main class?

Comment: @sstan What knd of details are you asking? I'm running as follow: java -jar [jarname]

Comment: @fabian yes, the manifest is called "manifest.mf" placed on the same directory as the jar and the second line is: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: firedartsfx.Main

Comment: @RicardoAlves: I'm more interested in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` **inside the jar**

Comment: @fabian https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45453297/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: @fabian pleas read my second edit. Does this have something to do that my application has JavaFX elements?

Comment: Seems likely. What's the java version you're using (command line)? `java -version`

Comment: I've updated my version in the computer I'm trying to run. It now shows as: java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the **jar** file and use [JWrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/) to build an executable. This will make it easier than using a console to run your project.